# Python - wrong answer in finding the no of bases that start with one for a given number

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

What am I doing wrong?

Given some integer N, how many bases(like decimal has a base of 10 and binary has 2) b are there such that the base-b representation of N starts with a 1?
I am trying this code for 9.

```
N = 9
base = 3
power = 10
count = 0
while base < 9:
    while power >= 0:
        if N >= base**power and N < 2*(base**power): count = count + 1
        power = power-1        
    base = base+1
#+2 for 2 and 9
print count+2
```

Comment: would you need to reset `power` ever outer `while` loop?

Comment: OK, I got it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following should work:

```
import math

num = 101
highestBase = 9
count = 0

for base in range(2, highestBase):
    largestUnder = base ** int(math.log(num, base))
    quot = num / float(largestUnder)
    if quot >= 1 and quot < 2:
        count+=1

print(count)
```